# Как перебрать многомерный json через нативный js?

Tags: javascript, json

Код

```js
let raskroy_json = {
  "1": {
    "korobka_name": "КСМ1",
    "raskroy": [{
      "profil_number": 1,
      "details": [{
        "detail_id": 2061,
        "order_item_id": 337,
        "size": 2015,
        "type": false,
        "zapils_count": 1
      }, {
        "detail_id": 2062,
        "order_item_id": 337,
        "size": 2015,
        "type": false,
        "zapils_count": 1
      }, {
        "detail_id": 2060,
        "order_item_id": 337,
        "size": 806,
        "type": false,
        "zapils_count": 2
      }]
    }, {
      "profil_number": 2,
      "details": [{
        "detail_id": 2063,
        "order_item_id": 337,
        "size": 806,
        "type": false,
        "zapils_count": 2
      }, {
        "detail_id": 2058,
        "order_item_id": 337,
        "size": 2016,
        "type": false,
        "zapils_count": 1
      }, {
        "detail_id": 2059,
        "order_item_id": 337,
        "size": 2016,
        "type": false,
        "zapils_count": 1
      }]
    }]
  },
  "2": {
    "korobka_name": "КСМ4",
    "raskroy": [{
      "profil_number": 1,
      "details": [{
        "detail_id": 2064,
        "order_item_id": 337,
        "size": 2015,
        "type": false,
        "zapils_count": 1
      }, {
        "detail_id": 2065,
        "order_item_id": 337,
        "size": 2015,
        "type": false,
        "zapils_count": 1
      }, {
        "detail_id": 2066,
        "order_item_id": 337,
        "size": 806,
        "type": false,
        "zapils_count": 2
      }]
    }, {
      "profil_number": 2,
      "details": [{
        "detail_id": 2067,
        "order_item_id": 337,
        "size": 2015,
        "type": false,
        "zapils_count": 1
      }, {
        "detail_id": 2068,
        "order_item_id": 337,
        "size": 2015,
        "type": false,
        "zapils_count": 1
      }, {
        "detail_id": 2069,
        "order_item_id": 337,
        "size": 806,
        "type": false,
        "zapils_count": 2
      }]
    }, {
      "profil_number": 3,
      "details": []
    }]
  }
}


console.log("Перебираем raskroy_json...");
for (let key in raskroy_json) {
  console.log("item", key, raskroy_json[key]);
  for (let detail in raskroy_json[key]['raskroy']['details']) {
    console.log("пробуем перебрать каждую деталь...");
    console.log("деталь: ", 'detail', raskroy_json[key]['raskroy']['details'][detail]);
  }
}
```

Первый цикл отрабатывает, второй ничего не отдает в консоль. Где ошибся? Мне нужно по очереди получать каждый объект лежащий в details, чтобы обрабатывать их.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raskroy_json[key]['raskroy']` это массив.

```js
const raskroy_json = {
    "1": {
        "korobka_name": "КСМ1",
        "raskroy": [{
            "profil_number": 1,
            "details": [{
                "detail_id": 2061,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2015,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2062,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2015,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2060,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 806,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 2
            }]
        }, {
            "profil_number": 2,
            "details": [{
                "detail_id": 2063,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 806,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 2
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2058,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2016,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2059,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2016,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }]
        }]
    },
    "2": {
        "korobka_name": "КСМ4",
        "raskroy": [{
            "profil_number": 1,
            "details": [{
                "detail_id": 2064,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2015,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2065,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2015,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2066,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 806,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 2
            }]
        }, {
            "profil_number": 2,
            "details": [{
                "detail_id": 2067,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2015,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2068,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2015,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2069,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 806,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 2
            }]
        }, {
            "profil_number": 3,
            "details": []
        }]
    }
}

console.log("Перебираем raskroy_json...");
for (let key in raskroy_json) {
  //console.log("item", key, raskroy_json[key]);
  for (let i = 0; i < raskroy_json[key]['raskroy'].length; i++) 
    for (let detail in raskroy_json[key]['raskroy'][i]['details']) {
         console.log("пробуем перебрать каждую деталь...");
         console.log("деталь: ", 'detail', raskroy_json[key]['raskroy'][i]['details'][detail]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const json = {
    "1": {
        "korobka_name": "КСМ1",
        "raskroy": [{
            "profil_number": 1,
            "details": [{
                "detail_id": 2061,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2015,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2062,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2015,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2060,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 806,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 2
            }]
        }, {
            "profil_number": 2,
            "details": [{
                "detail_id": 2063,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 806,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 2
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2058,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2016,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2059,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2016,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }]
        }]
    },
    "2": {
        "korobka_name": "КСМ4",
        "raskroy": [{
            "profil_number": 1,
            "details": [{
                "detail_id": 2064,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2015,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2065,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2015,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2066,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 806,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 2
            }]
        }, {
            "profil_number": 2,
            "details": [{
                "detail_id": 2067,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2015,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2068,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 2015,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 1
            }, {
                "detail_id": 2069,
                "order_item_id": 337,
                "size": 806,
                "type": false,
                "zapils_count": 2
            }]
        }, {
            "profil_number": 3,
            "details": []
        }]
    }
}

console.log("Перебираем raskroy_json...");
for(const el of Object.values(json)) {
    for(const sub_el of el['raskroy']) {
    console.log("пробуем перебрать каждую деталь...");
      for(const detail of sub_el['details']) {
        console.log("деталь: ", 'detail', detail);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Не убирайте возможность запускать ваш код со страницы. Это гораздо удобней, чем копировать ваш код и куда то вставлять. Обратите внимание на иконку для добавления javascript/html/css кода при ответе. Там есть автоматическое форматирование и после ваш код можно будет запускать со страницы